# How do I represent sums at different levels in Cognos 8?

Tags: cognos, cognos-8

I'm writing a report in Cognos. I want to represent all outstanding values for clients. This includes time we've worked but not billed (Unbilled) and unpaid invoices we've billed. Unbilled is a summed value with only one line. Invoices may have multiple lines as I want to keep the invoice number detail.

```
            Unbilled                  Outstanding
            --------                 -------------
client      Fees | Costs    invoice | invoice Date | invoice amt

ABC         $100   $25      B989       10/10/2013     $200
                            DD89       05/19/2013     $400
                            87R        07/14/2013     $300

XYZ          $11    0       

LMN           0     0       TRT11       01/01/2013     $500
```

Is this the best way to represent this, and if so, how do I do it? If not, how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a document that explained it. The document is called [Multiple Aligned Column Headers In Lists and Crosstabs](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/cognos/page368.html). I found it on the [IBM Developer Works website](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/).

HTH